# What are skulls for?

Tags: dead-island

I found a Blue Skull! It looks special! Whats it for? Are there others? In what Acts can I find each of any of the others?

**Do not tell me where the skulls are beyond the Acts they are located in please, I like a good treasure hunt.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Skulls](http://deadisland.wikia.com/wiki/Skulls) can be found throughout the game.  For each skull, there is a corresponding altar.  When you place the skull on the altar, you will unlock a special crafting recipe.

### Skulls

> Orange Skull: Act II.
>
> Green Skull: Act I.
>
> Purple Skull: Act II
>
> Blue Skull: Act II
>
> Brown Skull: Act I

### Altars

> Orange Skull Altar: Act II
>
> Green Skull Altar: Act II
>
> Purple Skull Altar Act II, during the quest Uninvited Guests.(Note: once the quest is completed, the Purple Altar becomes locked off.)
>
> Blue Skull Altar: Act I
>
> Brown Skull Altar

Comment: fwiw most of the recipes are pretty useless imo.  And you should put which act the skull is found in and which act the altar is in, since they can be from different acts.